# Error opening file (/tmp/buildd/ros-hydro-opencv2-2.4.6-3precise-20140303-2216/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:537)

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

This is my first post here so hopefully I will provide you with the right information.

I am running ROS Hydro on Ubuntu 12.04 through a virtual machine.

ROS seems to be working ok, I built my workspace using catkin and ROS is recognizing and compiling packages when I run catkin_make. I went through all of the tutorials without a problem.

When I try to run one of my nodes using rosrun sb_vision LineDetector.cpp I am getting this error: `Error opening file (/tmp/buildd/ros-hydro-opencv2-2.4.6-3precise-20140303-2216/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:537)`

I have deleted all of the source code that had anything to do with OpenCV and commented out things dealing with  OpenCV in the CMakeLists but it still has this problem.

I have sb_vision as a package and in it's src section there is Line_Detector.cpp, I have also included the CMakeLists.txt in sb_vision below. Other folders in sb_vision are: include, catkin, catkin_generated, cmake, CMakeFiles, devel, gtest,msg, test_results and package.xml.

`Line_Detector.cpp`:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include <sstream>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  //Initialize ROS
 ros::init(argc, argv, "Line_Detector");
  ros::NodeHandle n;
  ros::Publisher chatter_pub = n.advertise<std_msgs::String>("chatter", 1000);
  ros::Rate loop_rate(10);
  int count = 0;
  while (ros::ok())
  {
    std_msgs::String msg;
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "hello world " << count;
    msg.data = ss.str();
    ROS_INFO("%s", msg.data.c_str());
    chatter_pub.publish(msg);
    ros::spinOnce();
    loop_rate.sleep();
    ++count;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

---

Here is my CMakeLists.txt, I have tried commenting and uncommenting anything to do with OpenCV

`CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(sb_vision)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
  message_generation 
)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

add_message_files(
  FILES
  Num.msg
 
)

generate_messages(
   DEPENDENCIES
  std_msgs
)

catkin_package(
#  INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES sb_vision
   CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtime roscpp rospy std_msgs
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)

include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
include_directories(
  ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_executable(Line_Detector src/Line_Detector.cpp)

#target_link_libraries( Line_Detector ${OpenCV_LIBS} ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(Line_Detector sb_vision_generate_messages_cpp)
```

---

Any help would be much appreciated. If I can clarify anything or provide you with any more information I will happily do so. Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172456/error-opening-file-(/tmp/buildd/ros-hydro-opencv2-2.4.6-3precise-20140303-2216/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:537)/) by [rennis_02](https://answers.ros.org/users/18751/rennis_02/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-05-31

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> When I try to run one of my nodes using rosrun sb_vision LineDetector.cpp [..]

This seems strange: as far as I can tell from your `CMakeLists.txt`, the executable binary is called `LineDetector`, not `LineDetector.cpp` (which is the source file).

After building your workspace, source the `devel` workspace and see if this works:

```
rosrun sb_vision LineDetector
```

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-06-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rennis_02](https://answers.ros.org/users/18751/rennis_02/) on 2014-06-02**:
I remade the package, sourced the devel workspace and am able to run things now... I even added the OpenCV code back in and things are going well. You were right about the executable being called LineDetector not LineDetector.cpp.

Thank you!